# How to show the entire picture but in a smaller width and height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to display a picture with `background-image: url("mypic.png");`

Html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div id="example1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div id="example2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div id="example3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For example, I have 686x350 image. I want that no matter what, it will display on the background of the `#example1` and that ill see the full image, even if I resize the browser or something. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add your html and css in jsfiddle so that anyone can find the problem easily.

Comment: `# div {
    background: url(mypic.png);
    background-size: 686px 350px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}`

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To scale the background image to fit inside the div:

```
#example1{
      background-size: contain;
}
```

To scale the background image to cover the whole div:

```
#example1{
      background-size: cover;
}
```

See [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wGRD7/2445/)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need the `background-size: cover` property:

```
#example1 {
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This will scale the image to cover the entire element it is in, regardless of screen size / resolution.